# Is it possible to pre-define column data types?

Tags: oracle

When creating a table

```
Create table user(
username varchar2(30)
);
```

Is it possible to somewhere create a static or pre-defined data type?

```
short_name varchar2(30)
```

And then use this in the create table statement?

```
Create table user(
username short_name
);
```

Edit:
My initial thought was to build up and structure different varchar2 (and other data types) for easy reference when writing sql statements, example:

```
tiny_name varchar2(10)
short_name varchar2(30)
medium_name varchar2(60)
long_name varchar2(120)
```

The closest (I have seen so far) seems to be the use of TYPE, but that does not seem to cover what I am specifying in my question

Comment: That is called *User-Defined Datatypes*. We used them previously but then had problems debugging our stored procedures because there are not so much tools out there that can debug user defined types. But that is just a very special problem I guess.

Comment: No.  It can be done only in pl/sql (for pl/sql and SQL data type) using `subtype` keyword.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In plain SQL. Documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: @mathguy In plain SQL we create ADT(object types, collections), you cannot create constrained data types based on base data type ( `number(20)` or `varchar2(200)`) . Op wants to do the latter.

Comment: Why not? You create a data type "name" with a single member of data type `varchar2(200)`. Why would that not work?

Comment: I was reading up on TYPE, and from what I understand it makes an unspecific object with the content of the defined name & data type (like a table of sorts inside an object?) and not a new single new data type. If I am understanding this correct

Comment: @mathguy I didn't say it wouldn't work. We can make it work the question is why we wanna do it? Yes we can create an object type with one member of `varchar2(200)` for example. What we get from it? Every type we insert into the table we have to invoke object's constructor. We'll have to deal with data type inconsistency, if someone decides to insert just a character string, dependency issues and many more. It won't be a compatible with base data type constrained data type as OP wants it to be. It'll be a whole new data type.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I felt I had a smart thought about making a pre-defined Datatype, but I am starting to realize that this seems to be more work than what my question made it out to be. And that I might as well just use the standard way of creating a table :)

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - I see, and I agree. I thought the OP was looking to this as the first step in creating his own full-fledged type (eventually adding more attributes and possibly methods) - I read too much into the question! :-)

Comment: @mathguy I must comment that I now have read and learned a bit more about TYPE, and even though it does not cover my question, I can see a possible use for that later in my work :)

Comment: @Moptan: what you're looking for is what's referred to in other databases as a "domain". Personally, I like them - but Oracle doesn't support them as they have their object-oriented TYPE system instead. Frankly I think that TYPEs are too heavy-weight and DOMAINs are "just right", but clearly Oracle disagrees with me.

Comment: I usually define a set of domains in my modelling tool (SQL Developer Data Modeller) which then gets generated as base data types in the DDL. It's a pity TYPEs aren't better supported in the various tools, because it would be nice to be able to use them all the time.